# youtube API does not play normally

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

I think this playlist's music is not in playback. But youtube player state is started.
So press Pause button and control play bar, can play normally.
I want make normal state from the beginning.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="player"> </div><script>`

      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '360',
          width: '640',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
          }
        });
      }
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        player.loadPlaylist({'listType' : 'playlist', 'list':'myplaylist','index' : '0','startSeconds':'0','suggestedQuality':'default' });
        setTimeout(setShuffleFunction, 1000);   
      }
        function setShuffleFunction(){
          player.setShuffle(true);
        }

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

add capture
[Player State played (Pause button activate but music is not play)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpKkQ.jpg)

[Press Pause button and control play bar.->Can play music. But now music pause state, play button is not activate. Always Pause button on activate. But play/pause function is work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5kxX.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
 function onPlayerReady(event) {
        player.loadPlaylist({'listType' : 'playlist', 'list':'myplaylist','index' : '0','startSeconds':'0','suggestedQuality':'default' });
        setTimeout(setShuffleFunction, 1000);

        player.play(); 
      }
```